# Tallying in Scala DataFrame Array

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

I have 2 column spark Scala DataFrame. The first is of one variable, the second one is an array of letters. What I am trying to do is find a way to code a tally (without using a for loop) of the variables in an array.

For example, this is what I have (I am sorry its not that neat, this is my first stack post). You have 5 computers, each person is represented by a letter. I want to find a way to find out how many computers a person (A,B,C,D,E) has used.

```
+-----------------+--------------+
|       id        |   [person]   |
+-----------------+--------------+
|  Computer 1     |   [A,B,C,D]  |
|  Computer 2     |    [A,B]     |
|  Computer 3     |   [A,B,E]    |
|  Computer 4     |   [A,C,D]    |
|  Computer 5     |  [A,B,C,D,E] |
+-----------------+--------------+
```

What I would like to code up or asking if anyone has a solution would be something like this:

```
+---------+-----------+
| Person  |  [Count]  |
+---------+-----------+
|    A    |     5     |
|    B    |     4     |
|    C    |     3     |
|    D    |     3     |
|    E    |     2     |
+---------+-----------+
```

Somehow count the people who are in arrays within the dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

There's a function called `explode` which will expand the arrays into one row for each item:

```
| id | person

+-----------------+------------------------+

| Computer 1| A |
| Computer 1| B |
| Computer 1| C |
| Computer 1| D |

....
+---+----+----+----+----+
```

Then you can group by the person and count. Something like:

```
val df2 = df.select(explode($"person").as("person"))
val result = df2.groupBy($"person").count
```